# How to detect key release with python ( not keypress)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, msvcrt, keyrelease

### How can I detect key release with python 3 ?

Like if I pressed the key `a` for 1 second , when I remove my finger from the key *( releasing the key )* , It will `print("Key 'a' pressed then released")`.

I trying to do it with module [**`keyboard`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/) but I have no idea about how to use it for this. I used to detect keypress with it.
`msvcrt` module don't work for me but if `msvcrt` can do what I want , then you can answer me.

### Note:

**I Don't want to use `Pygame` or any other `module` which will show pop-ups**

Comment: [this?](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_release). You could follow a bit on the link you provided

Comment: Your module literally contains one example that does what you ask: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/examples/pressed_keys.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `pynput` module:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_key_release(key):
    print('Released Key %s' % key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_release = on_key_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

According to the documentation of [**`pynput`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) keyboard listener is a thread, which calls the function specified on `on_release` with the key argument. You can also specify a `on_press` function.

**Edit:**

As asked in discussions, you can stop the listener by returning `false` from the `on_key_release` function. Like that:

```
def on_key_release(key):
    print('Released Key %s' % key)
    return False
```

Comment: It's Good but make please make it more understandable.

Comment: pynput captures events globally, even when focus is not in the window of your application, which makes it inappropriate choice for implementing keyboard control in an application. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532462/pynput-reject-input-when-terminal-not-focused

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tkinter` for it:

```
from tkinter import *
def keyup(e):
    print('up', e.char)
def keydown(e):
    print('down', e.char)

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<KeyPress>", keydown)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: oh, it can be without pop up in other way i guess i am know this way maybe someone else know other way...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Acafed's answer, using tkinter and assuming you are using python3 you could easy do in this way:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Frame #importing only necessary stuff.

def keyrelease(e):
    print('The key was released: ', repr(e.char))

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
f.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyrelease)
f.pack()
root.mainloop()
```