# Detect key up and key down python3

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I am doing a program with python 3 that should print "w pressed" when I press and release a key. I tried, and when I press the key it prints all the time without being released.

Comment: Please include the code snippets that you have tried in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect key release with python ( not keypress)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584937/how-to-detect-key-release-with-python-not-keypress)

Comment: To detect the event of releasing a key likely requires very low level access to the operating system in question or the wrapping UI library, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27215326/1435475) for Tkinter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)